# How do I get this Jquery loop to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

It's straight forward, I don't know how to keep making it auto loop.

```
                <center><table id = "match_01">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Avatar</th>
                        <th>Rank</th>
                        <th>Wins/Losses</th>
                        <th>Accuracy</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span style="color:#29b;">Angelsim</span></td>
                        <td><img src = "https://a.ppy.sh/1777162_1453811024.png" width = "50"></td>
                        <td>#25</td>
                        <td>290 / 270</td>
                        <td>99.92%</td>
                    </tr>
                </table></center>

               <img src = "images/left_ar.png" id = "left_arrow" style = "left: 30%;position: absolute;"> <img src = "images/right_ar.png" style = "position:absolute;right: 30%;" id = "right_arrow"><h1>VS</h1>

                <center><table id = "match_001">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Avatar</th>
                        <th>Rank</th>
                        <th>Wins/Losses</th>
                        <th>Accuracy</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span style="color:#29b;">_index</span></td>
                        <td><img src = "https://a.ppy.sh/652457_1449676530.png" width = "50"></td>
                        <td>#13</td>
                        <td>190 / 136</td>
                        <td>98.89%</td>
                    </tr>

                </table>






                    <!-- Second Player -->   
                <center><table id = "match_02">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Avatar</th>
                        <th>Rank</th>
                        <th>Wins/Losses</th>
                        <th>Accuracy</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span style="color:#29b;">Cookiezi</span></td>
                        <td><img src = "https://a.ppy.sh/124493_1448724778.jpg" width = "50"></td>
                        <td>#1</td>
                        <td>290 / 270</td>
                        <td>99.92%</td>
                    </tr>
                </table></center>


               <div class = "invisble">  
               <img src = "images/left_ar.png" id = "left_arrow" style = "left: 30%;position: absolute;"> <img src = "images/right_ar.png" style = "position:absolute;right: 30%;" id = "right_arrow"><h1>VS</h1>
                </div>   


                <center><table id = "match_002">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Avatar</th>
                        <th>Rank</th>
                        <th>Wins/Losses</th>
                        <th>Accuracy</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span style="color:#29b;">Reimu-Desu</span></td>
                        <td><img src = "https://a.ppy.sh/948713_1453376392.png" width = "50"></td>
                        <td>#13</td>
                        <td>190 / 136</td>
                        <td>98.89%</td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
                    <div><b>Map:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><span style="color:#29b;">Everything Will Freeze [Time Freeze]</span></header><br><br>
                    <button>Spectate</button></center>
```

That's the HTML.  See rest of the code here.

https://jsfiddle.net/t0kgg0uw/10/

Basically it plays the loop once.. how can I make this infinite.
I'm not sure why the JSfiddle displays odd but here is the working thing with just 1 iterance.

https://gyazo.com/74e16127c6b40130a2176644ef4360e3

Really Need to fix this.

Comment: This is such a bad idea. You might make your browser inresponsive and asks users to disable their javascript for this website off.

Comment: @choz It's not something I'm keeping forever, just for experience.

Comment: @choz *"infinite"*  and *"loop"* doesn't necessarily mean what you are referring to. OP just wants to cycle the animations

Comment: Got it. Thought something was a bit off. Wasn't paying full attention.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a bad idea to make an infinite loop (i.e. `while(true) {}`), because that could freeze/crash the browser, like choz said. One idea could be wrapping your code in a `window.setInterval(function() {}, <delay in milliseconds>);`. The code in the function would run every `<delay in milliseconds>` milliseconds (1 second = 1000 milliseconds).

```
// Repeat every 20 seconds
window.setInterval(function() {
    // do something
}, 20000);
```

See [this Mozilla Developer Network listing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

Comment: @OsuCommunity can you post your code? It should end up looking something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/timtim17/28j685yh/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write all the code, just lay out the simple basics

Wrap all the animations in a function. Whichever animation is at the end , use it's completion callback to call the function again.

```
function page_animations(){
    $("#match_01").delay(2000).animate({left: '-1200px'});
     $("#match_001").delay(2000).animate({left: '-1200px'});


     ....
     // longest aniimation
     $(selector).delay().animate({/* properties*/}, duration, function(){
           // is now complete ... call function to start over
           page_animations();
     });
}
```

On page load call the function to get the cycle started

```
$(function(){
   page_animations();
});
```

You will need to do some figuring out of all the resets before they start again